# How do you return an instance of a variable class from within a different variable class?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I have a plugin with the structure something like:

```
variables
 - PluginVariable.php
 - PluginAnotherVariable.php
```

Inside `PluginVariable.php` I have something like:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class PluginVariable
{
   public function foo($parameter)
   {
       $result = craft()->plugin_results->get($parameter);
        return new PluginAnotherVariable($result);
   }
}
```

Now when I do `{{ craft.plugin.foo('something') }}` I just get `Fatal error: Class 'Craft\PluginAnotherVariable' not found`.

I've checked that the filenames and classnames are identical and the namespacing etc so the class most certainly exists but I can't get this to work, has anyone had a similar issue with this and what could be causing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boom!

So I just needed to put an underscore between the plugin handle and variable name so `PluginAnotherVariable.php` becomes `Plugin_AnotherVariable.php` and the classname `Plugin_AnotherVariable` and things are now working :)